# Does reloading / refreshing a page redownload any ajax / javascript scripts / documents?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, scripting, reload

I have a web page that loads a javascript file and a text file via Jquery's GET ajax call.  My question is this:  If I have a link on that page that sends you to the same page but with url variables (ie www.mysite.com -> www.mysite.com?id=10), does it re download the entire javascript file and text document, or will those be saved in the cache?  And if it IS redownloading the text file, is there a way to keep it in the cache and call it from the cache for each subsequent reload (do a check for it in cache and call that up if it is there)?

I ask because I don't want to make the user re download the files every single time just because I have links going to the same page.

And yes I know I'm better off making it dynamic so the page doesn't have to refresh.  For the sake of the question, though, please assume it has to be set up this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each file is cached in a separate way. The fact you change the URL of the parent file doesn't force the reloading of the other files if their URL doesn't change.

So don't worry : when you look at another SO question, you're NOT downloading the images and js files again.

If your question regards the parent file, that is the one that is directly loaded, yes it is reloaded if you change the URL. You can't avoid that. But you can make it very small and insignificant by having most of the content (js, images) in separate files whose URL is constant.

Comment: What do you mean by parent file?  And is it considered a URL change if the only change in the URL is the addition of variables?  I'm specifically worried about the ajax call to the text file.  If the file gets big, I don't want it to have to be reloaded each time a variable in the url changes

Comment: Yes, if you just change `?v=1` to `?v=2`, the html file will be reloaded. There is no way for the browser to guess it's supposed to be the same.

Comment: Ok so the consensus is that the text file that is being called up via jquery IS re downloaded every time the page variables change?

Comment: The server can exercise some control over caching via the Cache-Control HTTP header. So if the browser has already downloaded the file with `?id=10` and the Cache-Control header allows caching, it could reuse this result.

Comment: would it resuse it with ?id=11 though?  or will it view that as a completely new url and automatically re download it?

Comment: It would download it again. You have to understand that in old times the pages with CGI parameters were only server side generated (all this was designed before javascript) so if the parameters are different, the pages are supposed to be different.

Comment: That is very unfortunate to hear. Any idea if there is a way to manually cache a loaded file and to check for / call it up locally?

Comment: You *might* be interested by [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) but are you sure you **really** have a problem ? You're complaining about the standard cache system that everybody use and which is rarely a problem. Your main page can usually be very small, the big things are in the constant child files (js, images, css) which *are* cached.

Comment: I am more worried about the pages future than anything else.  Right now it loads a 82kb text file, but that *could* expand to MB's in the future.  I wouldn't want to make the user reload a couple MB's every time they are viewing different variables on the page

Comment: There is your problem : a page without the images and css **must not** be sized in MB. How is that possible ?

Comment: Because the page is loading a txt file (which is really just xml) to display data.  The xml file can / will grow and I want to ensure it will not be a problem in the future

Comment: If that's a different file from the main (HTML) one and you're always loading it with the same URL, the cache will be used.

Comment: But again, mysite.com?v=1 is not the same url as mysite.com?v=2 right?  If they are considered different urls, and therefore it re loads the entire txt document each time - then I need to rethink my approach